# Web Api model binding with file attachments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a model that named Event.

```
public class Event { 
  public int  Id {get; set;} 
  public string Name {get; set;} 
}
```

And I use `Event` in controller action method.

```
    // POST api/events
    [HttpPost]
    public CreateEventResponse Post(Event request)
    {
        return new CreateEventResponse { Id = 123 };
    }
```

[image]

This works.

But sometimes later I need attach file to Event while saving.

I am selecting **Upload file** from fiddler, but Content Type is changed as `multipart/form-data;`

[image]

But this time **`Event`** is not binding by model binder in controller action.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest that your file upload/attachment method be in a different controller method than you non-upload event-posting method. The file handling logic likely to be very different from the normal model handling logic and it will make it easier if you break it into two methods.

As for how to handle a file upload in WebApi, check out this:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AngularJS-with-Web-API-22f62a6e

When you upload a file, WebApi doesn't bind it to the method parameters as normal, you have to explicitly fetch the data using a clas that extends MultipartStreamProvider

Comment: What do you want to do with the file once it's attached?